# if statement for multiple string variables - check for two valid values out of five strings

Tags: php, if-statement

I have 5 string variables ($a, $b, $c, $d, $e)

What I am trying to do is check if more than 2 of the variables are empty.
[$x == ' ']

Here is what I have started with which will test if **1 or more** of the variables are equal to ' ':
`if ($a == '' || $b =='' || $c =='' || $d =='' || $e ='')`

But want I want to do is check if any **2 or more** of the variables equal ' '

I know there must be a better way than elseifs for every iteration.

**a, b, c,** <strike>d</strike>, <strike>e</strike>

**a, b,** <strike>c</strike>, <strike>d</strike>, **e**

**a, b,** <strike>c</strike>, **d**, <strike>e</strike>

<strike>a</strike>, **b, c, d**, <strike>e</strike>
etc....

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: You could use `array_filter()` or `array_reduce()` with `count()` and check if you put all those variables inside an array and filter them if 2 or more remain.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
$arr = [$a, $b, $c, $d, $e];
$num_empty = count(array_filter($arr, function($a) {
   return $a === '';
}));
$more_than_two_empty = $num_empty >= 2;
```

[array_filter](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-filter.php)

Comment: `array_filter()` without a specified callback will filter way more stuff than just the empty string `""`, which OP wants to filter. It will filter out `0`, `false`, `NULL`, `"0"`, `array()`.

Comment: @Rizier123 true; i initially read the question as if the op knew in advance the variables would either contain a string or the empty string.

Comment: That's really good to know. I am looking to only test for an empty string. All others would be strings. I will be testing now. Thank you so much!